# How to split the return of socket,gethostbyaddr and write to file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, gethostbyaddr

I have a script that reads addresses from a file and looks up its hostname with socket.gethostbyaddr, however the return of this function is messy and doesn't look right.

The line where it writes to the destination file reads:

```
destfile.write(str(socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)))
```

The results come out like this when it reads 8.8.8.8:

```
('google-public-dns-a.google.com', [], ['8.8.8.8])
```

However, I only need that first output, google-public-dns-a.google.com. I hope to have it write to the file and look like this:

```
8.8.8.8 resolves to google-public-dns-a.google.com
```

Anyone know how to split this? Can provide more code if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the first step is to split the one-liner up into multiple lines:

```
host = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
```

Now, you can do whatever you want to that. If you don't know what you want to do, try printing out `host` and `type(host)`. You'll find that it's a `tuple` of 3 elements (although in this case, you could have guessed that from the string written to the file), and you want the first. So:

```
hostname = host[0]
```

Or:

```
hostname, _, addrlist = host
```

Now, you can write that to the output:

```
destfile.write('{} resolves to {}'.format(ip, hostname))
```

Another way to discover the same information would be to look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr), which says:

> Return a triple (hostname, aliaslist, ipaddrlist) where hostname is the primary host name responding to the given ip_address, aliaslist is a (possibly empty) list of alternative host names for the same address, and ipaddrlist is a list of IPv4/v6 addresses for the same interface on the same host (most likely containing only a single address).

Or to use the built-in help in the interpreter:

```
>>> help(socket.gethostbyaddr)
gethostbyaddr(host) -> (name, aliaslist, addresslist)

Return the true host name, a list of aliases, and a list of IP addresses,
for a host.  The host argument is a string giving a host name or IP number.
```

Comment: Looks great! I like the first method you mentioned. After reading the docs, I understood that it returned a triple. I was just unsure how to separate the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is unpack the tuple holding the information you want. There are multiple ways to do this, but this is what I would do:

```
(name, _, ip_address_list) = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
ip_address = ip_address_list[0]
destfile.write(ip_address + " resolves to " + name)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Wasn't sure how to unpack the tuple properly.